# Customizing Devise vs Creating own authentication for multi page registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm creating a ruby on rails project (soon to be a mobile app). I wanted to utilize the Devise gem for authentication, but I am struggling with the customization of Devise. I wanted to implement a multi-page registration/sign up process. The standard devise gem automatically provides a form that includes email and password. For my project, I wanted the users to add in their name on one page, then their email on the next page, and then their password on the page after, etc. Please see the [attached jpg picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ted.jpg) for a super basic example.

So far, I separated the registration controller from the devise package. The registration controller comes with the new.html.erb and the edit.html.erb files. I want to take the standard form in the new.html.erb file and split that into multiple html.erb files. The controller would obviously need to be connected to these multiple files. As I was working on it, I realized how complicated it is. I'm wondering is it better to create my own authentication process instead of devise, or is it better to stick with devise?

I really want to make it work with devise, so if you have any suggestions on how to customize the gem to implement the multipage registration that I want, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps consider using the Wizard gem to help simplify this type of multi-page registration. First use devise to handle the username and password, and then use wizard to do what you want.

Comment: Devise doesn't do anything special in terms of registration. You can do whatever you want to create a new user, even from the console a la `User.create(email: "hi@example.com", password: "password")`

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I looked into Wizard and I think it fits best with what I'm looking for. Thank you for that suggestion. I had a follow up question. Wizard is referring to the type of form and the gem that we need to utilize is wicked right? Or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: https://github.com/schneems/wicked you are right it is wicked, not wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by modifying the views and the devise controller to accept multi-part registration, but it is cumbersome: I would counsel you to avoid it. Rather, another option would be to: (i) use devise to handle the email and username in one form and then (ii) handle the multi-part registration using the [wicked gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) - whose sole purpose for existence is to handle multi part registration problems.